# Does the TARDIS translate alien languages if the Doctor is sleeping?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

In *The Christmas Invasion*, the Sycorax language cannot initially be understood. At around the same time as the Doctor wakes up, they appear to begin speaking English.

Does this mean that the TARDIS doesn't translate alien languages while the Doctor is asleep?

Answer (score 7):

Jo Grant has no problems communicating with the Thals in Planet of the Daleks while the Doctor is unconscious. So the Doctor's state of consciousness doesn't appear to be connected to the translation ability of the TARDIS.

[image: Jo and a Thal]

Given that it ended when the Doctor woke up, the translation failure in The Christmas Invasion can most likely be attributed to the TARDIS suffering, via the symbiotic link, the effects of the Doctor's regeneration trauma.